# Postfix not receiving mail for virtual domain from outside (only locally)

Tags: postfix, virtualization, host

I have postfix mail server running at `mail.123.com` (ip eg 1.1.1.1), then I have site `books.com` (ip eg 2.2.2.2) and it's DNS records like this:

- MX record as mail.123.com
- A record mail.books.com same IP as books.com - I have this sub domain only due SPF checking, but that's not important for my problem)

Now, if I send mail to *info@mail.123.com* from outside, the message is delivered.

If I send mail to `info@mail.books.com` from outside message is NOT delivered.

If I send mail to `info@mail.books.com` from `localhost` of `mail.123.com`, message IS delivered. (via `telnet localhost 25`)

`/var/log/mail.err` is empty, `/var/log/mail.log` does not contain anything about not received mail or so.

Gmail (third email which is sender) does not get any error mail from mail server, like message not delivered.

What could be problem?

**Does Postfix need some special settings if the mail server is set as MX record for other domain?**

Now i have only the "virtual (host mail) domain" mail.books.com in

`virtual_alias_domains` and `virtual_alias_maps` of `/etc/postfix/main.cf` as said here [ubuntu documentation: PostfixBasicSetupHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixBasicSetupHowto)

I am unable to track why receiving of mail for my virtual domain doesn't work :(

Btw interesting is, if i didn't have MX record for books.com gmail even didn't complain while sending mail to info@mail.books.com !!! But then i realized i didn't set the MX record so i set it, but still does not work.. and it is like 2-3 hours yet, so i don't assume it is problem of MX record (due slow renew of cache of DNS).

Comment: If the delivery attemp (e.g. from gmail) reaches your server then postfix will log the reason why it rejected it. If nothing is in logs, then the msg didn't reach the server and you have DNS issue.

Comment: hmmm ok, thank you for reply.. ok i will see next day if it will be better. but anyway, it is strange that gmail does not complain eg in case if i forgot MX record.. that's bit unreliable. now it still doesnt work.. it is strange.

Comment: If `MX` record does exist, according to RFC it should try `A` record (for the part after `@`).

Comment: So is my settings good? info@mail.books.com where mail.books.com is only A for 2.2.2.2 and domain books.com has MX record mail.123.com. Now it bit confused me, how it works. Since it knows the domain of email info@mail.books.com (mail.books.com) but what it does with this domain? It will translate it to IP? Then what it will do with ip? If MX records are related to root domains like books.com not to IP's. I am confused myself now. May be the hour is too late :P.

Comment: It doesn't matter what is after @ (if it is domain.com, sub.domain.com, a.b.domain.com). To send mail, it queries MX record for the after-@ part. If you want to use @mail.books.com, then you need MX for that and not for books.com. That `A` record lookup is only a fallback, don't count on it.

Comment: I see ! aha, that could be the problem ! MX record can be set also for subdomains, that means as you say, **i need MX record for the part after @**. But in domain administration of my hosting i can only add MX record like mail.com and priority, **but not the subdomain the MX record is related to**, so it sucks ! that will be the problem hmmmm. Ok, may be i don't need to rely on subdomain mail. after @ even due SPF (because i can set the SPF rule also for root domain books.com) Ok i will try it.

Comment: haha! you are genius! now it works! i must write this behind my ears to remember it :) thank you very much. receiving for info@books.com works, since there is MX record for books.com.

Comment: yes, i will select the solution below, because you didn't write the answer but comments, but thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you  write it seems that you have an MX record for books.com but you are trying to send emails to info@mail.books.com.

That should be info@books.com or you should have an MX for mail.books.com.

Answer (score 0):

For days I was struggling with this and eventually realized that my ISP (Comcast) blocks ports 25, 465 and 587.

My solution was to use AWS SES and forward the message content over HTTP to a custom port.